# Как найти самое популярное имя?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Задания сделал, кроме 6 и 7. С коими и возникли вопросы. Не понимаю как к ним подойти. Простой count по столбцам выдает ошибки или не то что нужно. Почему с числами все нормально работает а со строками выкидывает ошибки? Каки их преобразовывать. Киньте, пожалуйста, в меня ссылкой что можно почитать? или какую идею можно здесь применить?
[Pandas Titanic](https://github.com/Yorko/mlcourse.ai/blob/master/jupyter_russian/topic01_pandas_data_analysis/lesson1_practice_pandas_titanic.ipynb)

Подскажите, пожалуйста, делает " \ "  в данном случае и какова его роль? [код взят здесь](https://github.com/Yorko/mlcourse.ai/blob/master/jupyter_russian/topic01_pandas_data_analysis/lesson1_pandas_intro_inclass_dirty.ipynb)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы показать N самых популярных имён можно воспользоваться методом [Series.value_counts()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
data[“name”].value_counts()[:N]
```

Comment: Ответ писал с iPhon’а, поэтому все кавычки надо заметить на обыкновенные...

Comment: не совсем понимаю. Нужно как то проиндексировать столбец имен? что бы iloc сработал.

Comment: можете ли посоветовать хорошие книги или статьи по пандам? Где разбирается на максимально простом уровне?

Comment: MaxU, спасибо за метод, погуглил, прорешал похожие примеры и нашел решение!

Answer (score 1):

Это знак продолжения строки кода.

```
a = b
эквивалентно
a = \
    b
```

Используется, как правило, для того, чтобы уместить код в определенную ширину.

Comment: спасибо, теперь понятно.  Я то думал это у меня код криво отображается на экране.